# Python virtual environment not working

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have activated the python virtual environment, but anyway when I run `pip install *`, the dependencies are installed to my local Python path. The same happens when I run the server in my Django project: `python manage.py runserver` -> the system is not using the virtual environment, but the python from my PC. What is the problem? Why my activated virtual environment does not work?

I am using MacOS. Everything worked until I erased all my data and installed again Python.

Thank you!

Comment: When you activate your virtualenv, what do you get when you do `which pip`?

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` env variable -- you may need to delete the global `site-packages` path -- or just get rid of it entirely (`export PYTHONPATH=`) -- or possibly set it to your project directory -- and then `pip install`. I've always found it annoying that `virtualenv` doesn't manage this properly by default...

Comment: @idjaw `/usr/local/bin/pip` . It is not the path of my virtual env

Comment: @KateCebotari Yeah, most likely a path issue. Read the comment that Joseph wrote. That is most likely what is going on.

Comment: Where could I find the PYTHONPATH? I have no .bash_profile file after I reinstalled the macOS

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` <-- type that in terminal -- if nothing comes up, then it is not the problem

Comment: it returns empty line

Comment: ....and now it has gotten mysterious. :)

Comment: I am not sure, but it may be a usefull info. I have installed python through brew. Maybe to try to remove it and install it in another way?

Comment: brew is usually pretty clean with the paths. But, funny enough, a lot of people facing these issues have always installed it using brew. Try re-installing your virtualenv but with the `--no-site-packages` to see if that helps?

Comment: check that your `virtualenv` is set up properly, created a subfolder in  your project, and it is active (`source venv/bin/activate` -- if you installed it to `venv`). `which pip` should be returning a path to your project directory and the `venv/bin/pip` subdir (at least -- for python 2.7 on my machine it does)

Comment: so I don't know what the problem is. I have downloaded and installed again python3 from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/ . After that I tried again to use my virtual env, but it again was not working. I have created a new virtual env, and then it started working. I don't know why the virtual env that I restored from another PC is not working

Answer (score 0):

If the packages aren't getting installed within your virtual environment, it most likely is the case that you are not using the pip within your virtual environment (or may not have pip within your virtual environment at all, in which case it is defaulting to use the pip installed in /usr/local/bin/). First, check that you have a separate version of pip in your virtual environment located in ./your_virtual_environment_name/bin/pip....If you don't, install from the PyPA download page (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py). When you go to install a package within your virtual environment, activate the virtual environment first using source ./bin/activate inside your virtual environment, then "cd .." and you'll use the pip installed within the virtual environment by typing: ./your_virtual_environment_name/bin/pip install *      ....The installation will be in ./your_virtual_environment_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/